# Making a new view appear after a UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a Tab Bar controller with a default view that calls an UIImagePickerController. Once the image gets saved by "Use Picture" then I want a new view controller to load without showing the starting tab bar view.  Is this possible?

Everytime I dismiss the impage picker it goes back to the tab bar view controller. Do I have to make the call for the image picker from the controller I want to return too?

Answer (score 0):

ImagePicker view when dismissed will return back to its parenting controller, If you want to navigate into some other controller after dismissing, I suppose you can call another controller after a delay with a loader on view,

If you call the other controller without an error it may lead to a crash or a warning, like"trying to present one controller while dismissing another"…

this is what I did to avoid this,

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   [SVPRogressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
    [self performSelector:@selector(goToNext:) withObject:image afterDelay:0.5];

}

and then 

-(void)PRESENTIMAGE:(UIImage *)IMG{

//Got to nextCOntroller where you want …and use the Image
[SVPRogressHUD dismiss];

}
```